# Can we get result of left outer join using right outer join

Tags: sql, join

Can we get the results of a left outer join using a right outer join?

Comment: of course, by exchanging the table positions

Comment: As already said, you can. I'd follow up with Why? There are good reasons to use Right Outer Joins, but they are unusual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  A right (outer) join is equivalent to a left (outer) join with the position of the tables switched.

Hence, the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col = t2.col
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
RIGHT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.col = t2.col
```

Comment: I usually recommend left join instead of right join, because it's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: @jarlh I agree with you.  I wanted to comment on why it seems that left joins tend to be favored nowadays over right joins, but didn't have any concrete documentation on that.